# How to make webpage not change when smaller/larger window

Tags: html, css

I am currently attempting to make a website for my college assignment, and I have come across the following problem:

When I make the window size smaller when my website is open in a browser, all of the pictures and text mess up. E.G, making the window bigger will make the pictures go out of line, and the text will lengthen. 
I want to make it so whenever you make the window size bigger, the text + pictures will stay central, leaving the same amount of space to the left and right of them, so it doesn't look stupid.

Code:

```css
<style>
 .contentAbout{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
 }
 #container{
  
 }
 .aboutImages{
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
 }
 #imageOne{
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-top: -145px;
  display: relative;
  border: 3px outset white;
  width: 440px
 }
 #imageTwo{
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
  width: 440px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  border: 3px outset white;
 }
```

```html
<div class = "contentAbout">
 <h2 id = "aboutUs">About us</h2>
    <p> Hey</p>
</div>
<div class = "aboutImages">
 <img id = "imageOne" src = "http://i.imgur.com/6kbSaGL.png" alt = "Car"/>
    <img id = "imageTwo" src = "http://i.imgur.com/SEl4ssJ.png" alt = "Car"/>
</div>
```

Comment: 'responsive design' are keywords - you will get plenty of results...

Comment: I think OP is looking for the opposite, must be nostalgia.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that you put them in a container with a set width, rather than directly under `<body>` whose default width is `100%` (rather, it's `auto`, which defaults to 100% of the parent's width).

```
<div class="top-level-container">
    <div class = "contentAbout">
        <h2 id = "aboutUs">About us</h2>
        <p> Hey</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "aboutImages">
        <img id = "imageOne" src = "http://i.imgur.com/6kbSaGL.png" alt = "Car"/>
        <img id = "imageTwo" src = "http://i.imgur.com/SEl4ssJ.png" alt = "Car"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then give `.top-level-container` a pixel width (or `max-width`/`min-width`, if you want it to have some freedom when the browser resizes.

Please note that there are more mobile users than desktop users, so don't discriminate those with a smaller screen!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make it responsive you should change the width from % to px (contentAbout)

If it is just an internal project it should be fine if its not responsive.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use media queries check out this link for more info:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp